# General formula involving ordinals

Tags: analysis, set-theory, ordinals

Let $X$ be a metric space. Suppose $(f_{\eta})_{\eta < \omega_1}$ is a sequence of real-valued functions on $X$ where $\omega_1$ is the first uncountable ordinal.

Let's say we have a sequence of subsets $(A_{\xi})_{\xi < \omega_1}$ such that $A_{\eta}$ is strictly decreasing, that is, $A_{\eta+1} \subsetneq A_{\eta} $ all $\eta < \omega_1$. Furthermore, $A_1$ is related to $f_1$, $A_2$ is related to $f_3$, $A_3$ is related to $f_5$, $A_4$ is related to $f_7$, and so forth.

When both $\xi$ and $\eta$ exceed $\omega$, then we relate them in the following way: $A_{\omega+1}$ is related to $f_{\omega +1}$, $A_{\omega +2}$ is related to 
$f_{\omega +3}$, $A_{\omega +3}$ is related to $f_{\omega+5}$, $A_{\omega +4}$ is related to $f_{\omega+7}$, and so forth.

When both $\eta$ and $\xi$ exceed $\omega \cdot 2$, then we relate them in the following way: 
$A_{\omega \cdot 2+1}$ is related to $f_{\omega \cdot 2 +1}$, $A_{\omega \cdot 2 +2}$ is related to 
$f_{\omega \cdot 2 +3}$, $A_{\omega \cdot 2 +3}$ is related to $f_{\omega \cdot 2+5}$, $A_{\omega \cdot 2 +4}$ is related to $f_{\omega \cdot 2+7}$, and so forth.

Question: How to obtain a general formula so that we have $\xi$ in terms of $\eta$? If $\xi$ and $\eta$ are just natural numbers, that is, before they exceed $\omega$, one can have $\xi=\frac{\eta +1}{2}$.

However, division is not well-defined for ordinals. Can someone give some hint on how to obtain a general formula?

UPDATE: Is the following statement correct?

If $\eta = \omega^{\alpha} \cdot \beta + \gamma$ for some $\alpha, \beta$ and $\gamma$, then $\xi = \omega^\alpha \cdot \beta + \frac{\gamma +1}{2}$.

Comment: $A_{\xi}$ and $f_{\eta}$ are related in a complicated way, which I refrain from stating here, as it would only complicate the situation.

Comment: @bof: Do you mean $\eta = \xi \cdot 2 -1$? But one cannot simply perform subtraction between ordinals, as it is not defined for limit ordinal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have specified a relationship between the $\xi$s and the $\eta$s over the naturals.  You have not specified what happens at limits or beyond.  One reasonable approach if the $f$s and $A$s are convergent would be to say $f_\omega$ is related to $A_\omega$ and then keep going.  In that case the infinite part of the ordinal would be the same between $f$ and $A$ and you would apply the same function to the finite part.

With the edit, you are requesting exactly what I suggested above.  Write the indices in Cantor normal form, copy over all the terms involving $\omega$, and apply your function $\xi=\frac{\eta +1}{2}$ to the finite part.  What you added in UPDATE is correct, but does not cover all the cases.  You can have $\eta=\omega^3\cdot 7+ \omega^2\cdot 9 + 1007$ and would want $\xi=\omega^3\cdot 7+ \omega^2\cdot 9 + \frac {1007+1}2$.

Comment: If $\eta = \omega^{\beta_n} + ... + \omega^{\beta_0} + \gamma$ for $\beta_n \geq ...\geq \beta_0$, then $\xi = \omega^{\beta_n} + ... + \omega^{\beta_0} + \frac{\gamma + 1}{2}?$

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  In the last equation there was an extra $\eta$.  Fixed.

Comment: I think I made a mistake in the Cantor's normal form above. It should be: If $\eta = \omega^{\beta_n} \cdot k_n + ...+ \omega^{\beta_1} \cdot k_1 + \gamma$ for $\beta_n \geq ... \geq \beta_1$ and $k_1,...,k_n$ are nonzero natural numbers, then $\xi = \omega^{\beta_n} \cdot k_n + ...+ \omega^{\beta_1} \cdot k_1 + \frac{\gamma +1 }{2}$.

Comment: Yes, that is more complete.  You clearly have the idea.  This is a well defined function from the odd ordinals to the ordinals where odd or even is defined by the finite part.